# Bootstrap conflicting with jQuery lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I´m using jQuery UI datePicker and jQuery UI toolTip and they work fine.
Then I also want to use the tagsManager from Bootstrap, but when I include the "bootstrap-tagmanager.js" and the "bootstrap.min.js" I start getting "TypeError: e is null" messages and neither the datePicker or the toolTip works.
(TypeError happens when click on the date-field for the datePicker).

Anyone has a work-around for this?

Comment: Please share the code required to reproduce the issue. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the javascript files in this order?

1. jquery.js
2. bootstrap.min.js
3. bootstrap-tagsmanager.js

look at: [Does the ORDER of javascript files matter, when they are all combined into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987977/does-the-order-of-javascript-files-matter-at-all-when-combined-into-one-files)

Comment: Yes, the scripts are in that order. It doesn´t seem to fix my problem.

Comment: It is the bootstrap.min.js include that is causing the problem. No solution found though...

Answer (score 0):

if you have conflit between jQuery file, use `$.noConflict();` before your $(document).ready();

Make sure that your lib call is good. Call first the jQuery and add bootstrap lib after.

Comment: Strangely enough the $.noConflict(); cause my program to fail with the error message (console): "TypeError: $ is not a function".

It even happens without the bootstrap libs.

I call "jquery.js", "jquery.min.js", "jquery-ui.min.js", then knockout.js before the bootstrap-libs

Comment: jquery.js and jquery.min.js are the same files. Difference is just that .min.js is a js file minimized, so unreadable. Moreover, the size change. You can remove jquery.js. And try `jQuery.noConflict(); ` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Ok, thanx. So I removed the query.js. and added the noConflict. Still the same error and nonworking date picker (unless I remove the bootstrap libs that is).

Comment: I need the website to find the problem. I can't help you more without code :/.

Comment: That´s a bi tricky as I´m developing on a local server... hmm. I can try to add an answer with what I´m trying to do...

Comment: Sjekk this: http://jsfiddle.net/U82Bv/1/

Here are part of my code and what I am trying to do.

The datepicker-calender does not show if I include the bootstrap libs, I can´t populate the input field with the date from the date picker. Also without bootstrap-libs I cannot get the tagsManager to work...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, `jQuery.noConflict()` will help you.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/#jQuery-noConflict1