# Sequence of loading JavaScript <script> files

Tags: javascript, dom, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to plot some graph for visualisation in the browser.
Therefore I've written a `.js` file which I'm loading in html code.
I received some strange issue, which I absolutely do not understand.

The following sequence of loading JS files is working without any error:

```
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

The following sequence of loading JS files throws an error:

```
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/line_chart/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The Error:

```
Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was provided.
    at nn.en (Chart.min.js:7)
    at n.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at he (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Object.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Qe.updateLayout (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Qe.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Qe.construct (Chart.min.js:7)
    at new Qe (Chart.min.js:7)
    at window.onload (line_chart_analysis.html:182)
```

The problem is that I'm using Bootstrap-Studio, where i cant change the sequence of implementation, because it's doing it automatically.

Is it possible to have the root cause in my created JS file?

I also used `ready` statement in my customized JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
});
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987977/does-the-order-of-javascript-files-matter-when-they-are-all-combined-into-one-f). It talks about when you need to worry about the order of your javascript files, and what your options are for situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Moment.js *before* Chart.js.

The Chart.js documentation could do a better job of highlighting this, but it is explained on the [installation page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html?h=moment#selecting-the-correct-build):

> The stand-alone build includes Chart.js as well as the color parsing library. If this version is used, you are ***required to include Moment.js before Chart.js*** for the functionality of the time axis.

If you can't change the load order then perhaps use the [bundled build](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js instead (and don't load Moment.js separately):

> The bundled build includes Moment.js in a single file. You should use this version if you require time axes and want to include a single file. You should not use this build if your application already included Moment.js. Otherwise, Moment.js will be included twice which results in increasing page load time and possible version compatibility issues. The Moment.js version in the bundled build is private to Chart.js so if you want to use Moment.js yourself, it's better to use Chart.js (non bundled) and import Moment.js manually.

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint! Now its working properly. Sometimes its and advantage to read the docs carefully :)