# When I use OwlCarousel nothing is displayed

Tags: jquery, draggable, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I want to use OwlCarousel and I used both the js and css files that are inside the OwlCarousel website and the cdnjs files, but when I add the files, nothing happens.
Can you please help me, where is the problem with my code?
I also followed a YouTube video, but it still didn't work.
[image: When I press f5, it only shows a white screen]

My code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: owlCarousel is a jQuery plugin so you need to load jQuery before owlCarousel in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html), you will find that [OwlCarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) has dependency with [jquery](https://jquery.com/). So, the order of the js file need to be [dependencies first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987977/does-the-order-of-javascript-files-matter-when-they-are-all-combined-into-one-f). In your code, you have owl.carousel.min.js before jquery.min.js. So, this order must be reversed. See the following example.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
   $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css' >
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please follow order of the js file need to be dependencies first.you have owl.carousel.min.js before jquery.min.js.
So, this order must be reversed. See the following example to solve your problem.**